# Use #temp inside a parenthesis

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, temp-tables

How use a #temp inside a parenthesis?

Or how to use a table variable inside a parenthesis?

Clearly the real query is much more complex.

Fails:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp 
CREATE TABLE #Temp (sID int NOT NULL);
select count(*) 
from 
(
  insert into #Temp 
  select top 10 sID from [docSVsys]  
  select * from #temp
) as [count] 
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Fails:

```
select count(*) 
from 
(
  IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp 
  CREATE TABLE #Temp (sID int NOT NULL);
  insert into #Temp 
  select top 10 sID from [docSVsys]  
  select * from #temp
) as [count] 
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Works:
But I need to use the #temp inside a parenthesis

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp 
CREATE TABLE #Temp (sID int NOT NULL);
insert into #Temp 
select top 10 sID from [docSVsys]  
select * from #temp
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: If you just need to know how many rows were `insert`ed, what's wrong with `@@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever From the question: "Clearly the real query is much more complex."

Comment: Just noticed your "the real query is much more complex" which may make my previous comment off target. But the issue really is, what are you trying to do? It's never a requirement to "put X in parenthesis" - you've not told us what your actual requirement is. All you've told us is that your perceived *solution* to a problem is "put X in parenthesis".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, but, looking for an answer to the stated question.

Comment: You might want to check [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The answer to the stated question is. "it can't be done".

Comment: If all you are doing is what is in the accepted answer then just do `select COUNT(*) from #temp`.

Comment: @MartinSmith As stated on line 3 of the question.  "Clearly the real query is much more complex."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only SELECT statements in parenthesis (subquery). But you can not use INSERT statement here (#-table does not matter). Try

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp 
CREATE TABLE #Temp (sID int NOT NULL);

insert into #Temp 
select top 10 sID from [docSVsys];

select count(*) 
from 
(
  select * from #temp
) as [count] 
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Or use [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28SQL.100%29.aspx) for complex case

Comment: Thanks worked.  Don't think output is I need for this.  Populating that #temp is expensive and then it is reused in some joins and unions to get "results".